# How can I change the destination folder of Grive?

Tags: 14.04, drive, google

I recently found Grive on the software center, and it seems like a very well made Google Drive client for Ubuntu, and Google will never make Drive for Linux, so I gave Grive a try. Works really well, but all I have is one question for all of you pros out there:  Is there any way to change the destination folder's location? The grive setup app looks like it links all the files and libs and shiz, so I'm sure you can change the script to work with a custom destination on your drive, but I myself am a bit too busy to do that. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to do it via the terminal.  On a fresh install of Grive, instead of running the Grive setup app run

```
grive -p path_to_your_preferred_folder -a
```

This command changes the Google Drive folder and starts the synchronization of files.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the grive folder to your desired location which most probably will be another drive on your system. Now to sync your files with google drive right click on the drive that have the grive folder and click open this in terminal. After that you will see the terminal here just type grive to start the syncronization process.

Comment: Can you include some screen shots to show the OP what you mean? Can you counter OP's statement that "Google will never make Drive for Linux" which implies he has insider information?